# Getting error for selenium test execution with jenkins on QAT server, it's working fine with local jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation

Currently, I am doing automation of a project and writing Tests thru selenium and java it's working fine when I am executing tests from 
  Jenkins on my local server but on QAT I am getting an error.Previously I have written selenium test and now I have started using Jenkins for build and integration with Git on my windows platform.
  Also, chrome path I am using for QAT server is  I have changed to

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Program Files

(x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SPOSAUTOMATION\workspace\Driver\chromedriver.exe");

```
  [INFO]  T E S T S
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Running TestSuite
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 
  (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 10309
  Only local connections are allowed.
  [ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time 
  elapsed: 21.404 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
  [ERROR] 
  launchBrowserTest(com.Spos.LoginAppUserAdmin.LoginAppUserAdmin)  Time 
  elapsed: 21.248 s  <<< FAILURE!
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
  Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
```

This is the log file generated after execution build test thru Jenkins on 
   QAT server of the application.Here chromedriver started execution but not getting connected with chrome server and throwing a timeout exception.
  Please ask me if any further information required to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your selenium server active on the machine you are trying to execute the code through Jenkins?

you can check that, and start the server on command line from the location where selenium standalone server is located. Try the following command(modify the paths) :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe
```

Comment: Yes,Selenium server is active on my machine even my tests are running succesfully on jenkins at http://localhost:8080 but when same code I am executing thru jenkins at http://192.168.10.91:8081 which is on QAT server I am getting above mention error logs.Is this problem is related to port chromedriver looking for???

Comment: That's unlikely to happen, if you are trying to execute runs on your machine through Jenkins hosted on QAT server, when run works fine with locally hosted jenkins, this might have been the problem if test machines were different.
It could be due to version incompatibility between selenium and chromedriver version. Check if you are using updated versions, for more help, visit: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1797

Answer (score 0):

Which OS you are using on your http://192.168.10.91:8081/ (server)? If it is Ubuntu then try executing scripts in headless mode and follow these steps:

1. Download and enable **Xvfb** before the start of selenium script on Jenkins. For more info read here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin
2. To be on safer side try to keep chromedriver in **"usr/bin"** folder.
3. Now run the script.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved after adding a headless mode option while executing tests on the Jenkins server.

```
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
            options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
            options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```